# How to connect 2 (and more) PCBs together to make them semi-modular?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, connector, pcb-assembly

So, I want to design PCBs with some LEDs on them and connect them together. The PCBs are about 2 cm wide and connection has got to be on this sides of the PCBs. I've tried some connectors but ones I used are too big and despite my research I couldn't find anything that fits.

I want to make the connections tight so it won't "fall off" while being used. Could someone give me any ideas as to what kind of connector I need to use?

Comment: Right angle board-to-board (B2B) connectors is what they are called but there are many kinds. Most are pretty big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solid state lighting (LED) industry developed a series of connectors specifically for your application. For example from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/solid-state-lighting-connectors/444).

https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/connectors-for-solid-state-lighting

Source, AVX through Digikey

[image: AVX Solid State Lighting Connectors]